# SQL CASE MORE THAN OR LESS THAN

Tags: sql-server

writing the case of more than or less than code is below

```
case

When  (case when a.SCode = 0202 and a.ItCodeD in ('37.01.123.0001','37.01.120.0001','37.01.105.0001'  ) 
and a.GDate between '2020-03-01' and '2020-03-31' then sum(a.appqty) end ) >= 10 then (a.AppQty * 1000)
When  (case when a.SCode = 0202 and a.ItCodeD in ('37.01.123.0001','37.01.120.0001','37.01.105.0001'  ) 
and a.GDate between '2020-03-01' and '2020-03-31' then sum(a.appqty) end ) <10  then (a.AppQty * 500)


end discamount
```

the multiplication is not working 
when sum(a.appqty) >= 10 then (a.appqty * 1000)
when sum(a.appqty) < 10 then (a.appqty * 500) 
Please help me in this

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to do. Sample data, desired results and a better explanation would help improving your question.

Comment: Please see the question again i have edited

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table
(
    SCode varchar(10),
    ItCodeD varchar(20),
    GDate date,
    AppQty int
)

insert into @t(SCode, ItCodeD, GDate, AppQty)
values('0202', '37.01.123.0001', '20200310', 4), ('0202', '37.01.105.0001', '20200310', 13),
-- gdate<'20200301', no disc
('0202', '37.01.123.0001', '20200202', 20), ('0202', '37.01.105.0001', '20200210', 40),
--SCode= 0201, no disc
('0201', '37.01.105.0001', '20200310', 100);

select *, 
case 
 when a.SCode = '0202' and a.ItCodeD in ('37.01.123.0001','37.01.120.0001','37.01.105.0001'  ) and a.GDate between '20200301' and '20200331' then
 case
    when sum(case when a.SCode = '0202' and a.ItCodeD in ('37.01.123.0001','37.01.120.0001','37.01.105.0001') and a.GDate between '20200301' and '20200331' then a.appqty end) over() >= 10 then a.AppQty * 1000
    else a.AppQty * 500
    --when sum(case when a.SCode = '0202' and a.ItCodeD in ('37.01.123.0001','37.01.120.0001','37.01.105.0001') and a.GDate between '20200301' and '20200331' then a.appqty end) over() < 10 then a.AppQty * 500
  end
else 0
end as discamount
from @t as a;
```

Comment: its working thanks my dear friend thank you so much amazing amazing awesome :)